# Web socket problem - secure connection to 127.0.0.1 - do i need to buy certificate?

Tags: websocket

What we have:
serverone.exe - util (like a local web proxy) which have support with Websocket.
After user opens a http site (abcd.com)  Browser (IE or Firefox) redirects some requests to serverone.exe via websocket.
This connection must be secure in order to browser work well. https -> https
So I have to buy a tls cert for 2 years? Right?
And use domain "test1.com" and then associate it with 127.0.0.1 in hosts.

Is there any other ways to do it nice? without certificates and hosts.
Sorry for my English.

Comment: Don't know much about .exe stuff, but if you need a secure connection you need https certificate. You can use LetsEncrypt for a free one which is perfectly legal and sounds like you can use just a server IP without the domain name.

Comment: Its not very convenient - you have to update this cert every 3 month on a hundreds of computers remotely....

Comment: Not sure why would you have hundreds of servers, but you can setup an automated renewal with a cron which is built into Certbot.

Comment: this is not servers. this is users-computers. we dont have remote control to them.

Comment: You can generate a local certificate (self-signed certificate) for the loop-back IP (127.0.0.1) and request admin privileges to add it to the trust list.